# Adding dot above navigation list elements on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a hover effect on my navigation links in my navbar to be a simple filled dot above the highlighted list item. I cannot seem to get anything to work. I had been trying the `:before and :after` css pseudo selectors. I did get a line to work using a border property  as well. Is there a simple way to do this.

html

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">link 1></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it is simple using before/after elements … add in a little absolute positioning, and you”re there already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
ul li:hover:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    background: red;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left:calc(50% - 8px);
}
```

and the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/f7RrW/

Comment: This worked. I was forgetting to position the before element.

Comment: Maybe you will find some other way (not using calc) as I guess it forces the browser to do some calculations. I just do it that way to be fast ;)